# How to set a TextView placeholder in Bottom sheet fragment from an adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have a BottomSheetDialogFragment class like this

**RenameWalletDialog**

```
public class RenameWalletDialog extends com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment  {

    EditText editTextWalletName;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rename_wallet_sheet, container, false);

        editTextWalletName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_input_et);

        view.findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Confirm button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        view.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        view.findViewById(R.id.clear_field).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                editTextWalletName.getText().clear();
            }
        });

        return view;

    }
}
```

and I created a function it in my adapter class like this

**WalletAdapter**

```
@Override
    public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx).inflate(R.layout.wallet_item, parent, false);
        final DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view);

        dataObjectHolder.walletoptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Option Click " + dataObjectHolder.getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                Log.d(TAG, "position = " + dataObjectHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(mCtx, R.style.popupMenuStyle);
                final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, v, Gravity.END);
                popup.inflate(R.menu.poupup_menu);

                popup.show();

                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.one:
                                showFragmentRenameWallet();
                                break;
                            case R.id.two:
                                //Do operation if menu_item_two
                                Toast.makeText(mCtx,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return dataObjectHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, final int position) {

        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
        Double doubleBalance = (double) userWalletList.get(position).getBalance();
        String numberFormatBalance = formatter.format(doubleBalance);
        holder.walletname.setText(userWalletList.get(position).getWalletName());
        holder.walletbalance.setText(String.valueOf( "₦ " +numberFormatBalance));
//        holder.walletid.setText(String.valueOf(userWalletList.get(position).getWalletid()));
        RenameWalletDialog renameWalletFragment = new RenameWalletDialog();
        renameWalletFragment.show(((FragmentActivity)mCtx).getSupportFragmentManager(), renameWalletFragment.getTag());
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        String walletN = userWalletList.get(position).getWalletName();
        bundle.putString("walletname", walletN);
        renameWalletFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userWalletList.size();
    }

    public interface MyClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }

    private void showFragmentRenameWallet(){
        RenameWalletDialog renameWalletFragment = new RenameWalletDialog();
        renameWalletFragment.show(((FragmentActivity)mCtx).getSupportFragmentManager(), renameWalletFragment.getTag());
    }
```

and use the function like this

```
showFragmentRenameWallet();
```

I think everyone now has a basic idea how my code logic works

I am trying to achieve;

1. I want to set the edit text view of the bottom sheet to the name of wallet the user clicks the rename option for

But I don't see any feasible way of doing this via the adapter, since it's not really a part of the adapter view

Does any one have any idea on how to do this?

NB: In the on bind view holder for my adapter, I get the wallet name like this

```
holder.walletname.setText(userWalletList.get(position).getWalletName());
```

Comment: You can pass `Bundle` to `BottomSheetDialogFragment` because its a `Fragment` ..

Comment: you want to set edit text present in fragment from Adapter is it?

Comment: @Keshav1234 yes

Comment: You can do that via interface. Implement the interface in fragment and call the interface method from adapter where ever required and send the text as argument to the adapter method

Comment: Sorry as an argument to interface method

Comment: @ADM that seems to make sense, but it sounds a bit fuzzy, how can I go about this?

Comment: @Keshav1234 I'm trying to gran the concept of what you are suggesting, but I don't understand it

Comment: @Kennedy from where is your adapter called is it from rename wallet dialog fragment??

Comment: @Keshav1234 no it's called in wallets frament , where I add the wallets from the database

Comment: Okay since you have object of wallet dialog in your adapter you can pass data via bundle or just create a method in fragment and pass the data to that fragment via that object

Comment: @Keshav1234 How can I pass the exact data via a bundle or using a method like you suggested, I don't know how to do this. Could you write a code snippet for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this if you want to pass data via bundle then

In Adapter:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle()
bundle.putString(SomeKey, value you want to send)
walletFragmentObject.setArguments(bundle)
```

Then in fragment

```
String text = getArguments.getString(SomeKey)
```

Update:

Change your method as shown below:

```
private void showFragmentRenameWallet(ViewHolder dataObjectHolder) {
    RenameWalletDialog renameWalletFragment = new RenameWalletDialog();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    String walletN = userWalletList
        .get(dataObjectHolder.getAdapterPosition())
        .getWalletName();
    bundle.putString("walletname", walletN);
    renameWalletFragment.show(
        ((FragmentActivity) mCtx).getSupportFragmentManager(),
        renameWalletFragment.getTag()
    );
}
```

Remove code related to bundle and RenameWalletDialog from onBindViewHolder.

Comment: I was able to set the bundle in my onBindViewHolder, but when I try and click on the button that shows the rename fragment it cashed, due to all null pointer when trying to get the bundle

Comment: `RenameWalletDialog renameWalletFragment = new RenameWalletDialog();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("walletname", userWalletList.get(position).getWalletName());
        renameWalletFragment.setArguments(bundle);`

Comment: But if I add this, `renameWalletFragment.show(((FragmentActivity)mCtx).getSupportFragmentManager(), renameWalletFragment.getTag());` to show the fragment once the view is created it automatically opens all the dialogs for all the wallets with the curret value, but I don't want it to auto open , rather open only when the user clicks a button

Comment: Add that .show code only onClick. Then it will not open the dialog automatically

Comment: if i add the code to the onclick listener, I get a null pointer exception while from the fragment when trying to access the bundlle

Comment: Please post the adapter code, how you are trying to acess the bundle in onClick listener

Comment: `getAdapterPosition()`  is not defined, do i need to have a method for that?

Comment: @Kennedy getAdapterPosition() is an inbuilt function in recyclerview, you don need to write a method for that

Comment: try to pass the holder in the method as I have edited and see if that solves the error

Comment: Please help take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61261413/ondateset-isnt-getting-called-in-android-5-1-1